# recursive parsing parenthesis with explanation

Tags: logic, recursion

I came across an explanation where `(()())()` gives you the sequence `0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,0` using recursive parsing. Can someone give me a **detailed** explanation of how this works?

Comment: It's starting with $0$ and then adding one for every "open parenthesis", '(', and subtracting $1$ for every "close parenthesis", ')'.

Comment: THANK YOU!! this just clicked in my mind!!

Comment: As you can see, this counting is just to find out where to split, before recursing.

Comment: It's just raise on an open bracket, lower on a closed bracket. $$0 \raise{0.5ex}{( \raise{0.5ex}{1 \raise{0.5ex}{( \raise{0.5ex}{2})}1 \raise{0.5ex}{( \raise{0.5ex}{2})}1})}0 \raise{0.5ex}{( \raise{0.5ex}{1})}0$$

Answer (score 2):

If your example is `(()())()` then you start at `0`

```
0 = split  
( = +1
) = -1
 +1 +1 -1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1
0  1  2  1  2  1  0  1  0
^                 ^     ^
 Split the parenthesis here
```

You get `(()())` `()`

Comment: I've fixed a slight error in your answer.

Comment: Answered my own question! Yay!